# Producing anova from already summarized data

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

I'm trying to run aov() on the above table, but I'm only able to create a partial output. I'm not sure how to include the standard deviation in the calculation.

Right now I'm concatenating and repeating each group like so:

```
groups <- c(rep('LHS', 121), rep('HS', 546), rep('Jr', 97), rep('Bachelors', 253), rep('Graduate', 155))
```

And then doing the same for the means (since I don't have access to the original data sheet):

```
means <- c(rep(38.67, 121), rep(39.6, 546), rep(41.39, 97), rep(42.55, 253), rep(40.85, 155))
```

At this point I can create a data fame and then run aov on it:

```
df <- data.frame(groups, means)
groups.aov <- aov(means ~ groups, data = df)
```

Unfortunately `summary(groups.aov)` only gives me a partial result.

```
              Df Sum Sq Mean Sq   F value Pr(>F)    
groups         4   2004     501 4.247e+27 <2e-16 ***
Residuals   1167      0       0
```

Any other way I can go, where I can factor in the SD?

Comment: Hi, you can use the SD.. but what would you like to get out from the anova?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We simulate some data so that we know the calculations are correct:

```
set.seed(100)
df = data.frame(
groups=rep(letters[1:4],times=seq(20,35,by=5)),
value=rnorm(110,rep(1:4,times=seq(20,35,by=5)),1))
```

We get back something like the table you see above:

```
library(dplyr)

res <- df %>% group_by(groups) %>% summarize_all(c(mean=mean,sd=sd,n=length))
total <- data.frame(groups="total",mean=mean(df$value),sd=sd(df$value),n=nrow(df))

rbind(res,total)

# A tibble: 5 x 4
  groups  mean    sd     n
  <fct>  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1 a      0.937 1.14     20
2 b      1.91  0.851    25
3 c      3.01  0.780    30
4 d      4.01  0.741    35
5 total  2.70  1.42    110
```

We always work with the sum of squares in anova. So from sd back to sum of squares, you usually multiply by n-1, and from there you can derive the F value. The detailed calculations:

```
# number of groups
ngroups=nrow(res)# number of groups
# total sum of squares
SST = (total$sd^2)*(total$n-1)
#error within groups
SSE = sum((res$sd^2)*(res$n-1))
aovtable = data.frame(
Df = c(ngroups-1,total$n-ngroups-1),
SumSq = c(SST-SSE,SSE)
)
aovtable$MeanSq = aovtable$SumSq / aovtable$Df
aovtable$F = c(aovtable$MeanSq[1]/aovtable$MeanSq[2],NA)
aovtable$p = c(pf(aovtable$F[1],aovtable$Df[1],aovtable$Df[2],lower.tail=FALSE),NA)
```

And we can compare the two results:

```
aovtable
   Df     SumSq     MeanSq        F            p
1   3 140.55970 46.8532330 62.62887 2.705082e-23
2 105  78.55147  0.7481092       NA           NA

summary(aov(value~groups,data=df))
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    
groups        3 140.56   46.85   63.23 <2e-16 ***
Residuals   106  78.55    0.74
```